# Getting TLE in solving SPOJ PT07Y

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search

[This](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Y/) is the link to the question.

It says given edges find if the graph is a tree or not.

I am checking if the number of edges is one less than number of node and if there is a cycle in the graph.

For checking if there is a cycle in the graph, I am marking the nodes as visited and if I face the same node again and it is not a parent. I am inferring it has a cycle.

I am doing it like below. It is giving me TLE. I am not able to figure out what optimization I have to do.

```
class Main{
    public static PrintWriter out;
    public static boolean isTree(int node,HashSet<Integer> hs,HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> graph, int parent){

        hs.add(node);
        LinkedList<Integer> children = graph.get(node);
        Iterator<Integer> it = children.iterator();
        boolean op = true;

        while(it.hasNext()){

            int child = it.next();

            if(child!=parent && (hs.contains(child) || !isTree(child,hs,graph,node)))
                return false;
        }

        return op;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();
        MScan scan = new MScan();
        int nodes = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<nodes; i++){
            graph.put(i+1, new LinkedList<Integer>());
        }
        int edge = scan.nextInt();
        if(nodes-edge!=1){
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out), true);
            out.println("NO");
            out.close();
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i < edge; i++){
                int first = scan.nextInt();
                int second = scan.nextInt();
                graph.get(first).add(second);
                graph.get(second).add(first);
            }
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out), true);
            out.println((nodes-edge==1)?isTree(1,new HashSet<Integer>(),graph,-1)?"YES":"NO":"NO");



            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tree with N edges has N+1 vertices. Ensuring that, test for connectedness.

Comment: @user58697 yes, I did that in last but one statement.

Comment: I don't see testing for connectedness.

Comment: Maybe replacing the HashSet<Integer> with a lighter boolean array (indicating for each node whether it was already reached) would help? Also, it is likely that I/O takes significant time. How is MScan implemented?

Comment: @qwertyman MScan uses BufferedReader. I will try with a boolean array. I am worried if isTree goes to infinite loop.

Comment: @user58697 sorry I dint understand what connectedness means.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Do not hunt cycles. Use quick union or similar to enumerate connected components. If you end up with a single component, it is a tree, otherwise not.

Comment: @qwertyman  finally accepted. Issue was with hashset. I used boolean array. And one more mistake was not thinking same edges are given again and again. Which boils to connected components I think.

Comment: @user58697 I thought I checked for connectedness by edges nodes subraction. Did not account for input with repeated edges. Did not use quick union. Did dfs from a node and counted nodes visited to total nodes. Thanks both of you,

Comment: @user168983 I see, great, thanks for the reply, I was really curious. So (if I understand correctly) the hashset was responsible for the TLE, and the other mistake caused some wrong answers (falsely accepting some invalid trees).

Answer (score 0):

Why have you used hashset? This is not necessary here. It will take time for storing and retrieving data. It is like a min_heap data structure (needing time for reshaping when you enter data).

So use a normal boolean array instead.
My C++ solution might help you to do this more efficiently

https://github.com/joy-mollick/Problem-Solving-Solutions/blob/master/SPOJ-PT07Y%20-%20Is%20it%20a%20tree.cpp

Comment: May I recommend not to answer with a rethorical question?

Comment: Answers are considered more valuable and future-proof, if they do not rely on external sites to convey information. Please provide the core of the anwer here directly.